# Receiving abortNative when trying to connect with Bluetooth in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm facing a weird issue with Bluetooth application in Android. The application I'm trying to develop is a Bluetooth ad-hoc network. And the issue is with the createInsecureRfcommSocket. I'm my application, when the user clicks the discovery button, it triggers a loop to try to connect to all discovered devices saved in linkedlist (I do the discovery beforehand). Then, each connected node based on this process will receive a discovery request and perform the same process recursively of trying to connect to all nodes it discovered beforehand except the node it received the request from. The issue I'm facing is that a lot of times, nodes will not accept to open a socket although they are already listening to a Bluetooth server socket and the log looks like:

```
02-09 17:36:21.898: I/BluetoothManetCommMgr(29670): Insitiating communication thread...
02-09 17:36:21.898: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): initSocketNative
02-09 17:36:21.898: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): ...fd 49 created (RFCOMM, lm = 0)
02-09 17:36:21.898: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): initSocketFromFdNative
02-09 17:36:22.078: D/BluetoothUtils(29670): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
02-09 17:36:34.085: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): abortNative
02-09 17:36:34.085: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): ...asocket_abort(49) complete
02-09 17:36:34.085: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): destroyNative
02-09 17:36:34.085: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(29670): ...asocket_destroy(49) complete
```

The snippet of code to register the server socket is basic reflection:

```
Method m = mBluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingInsecureRfcommOn", new Class[] { int.class });
tmp = (BluetoothServerSocket) m.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, 1);
```

while, at the client side I use the following code to connect:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

I then downgraded my requirement to connect all the clients manually beforehand. Meaning, I will let each Android phone perform the discovery beforehand and then connect an Android phone to another by clicking on a button on each device until I connect all devices. I still see the problem happening very frequently especially when the phone has just created a connection with a phone, then the second request to another phone is likely to fail with same above abortNative response. By the way, I used the regular createInsecureRfcommSocket without reflection and still the same problem is happening.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: I am no expert on this but this link have some sample which might help U - http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth/source/browse/branches/two_dot_o/AndroidBluetoothLibrary/src/it/gerdavax/easybluetooth/LocalDevice2Impl.java?r=58  Or maybe u knew this already :)